# JS regexp: exec(): "merge" different groups to the same result

Tags: javascript, regex

A simplified example: Using this regular expression

```
/^(?:(a)(b)|(c)(d))$/.exec(value);
```

results in an array of 5 elements if matching, either

```
["ab", "a", "b", undefined, undefined]
```

or

```
["cd", undefined, undefined, "c", "d"]
```

Is it possible to change the regular expression in a way to get the following results? Either

```
["ab", "a", "b"]
```

or

```
["cd", "c", "d"]
```

but still not matching "ad" or "cb"?

(Note that a, b, c, and d should be arbitrary complex regular expressions in reality).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use `Array#filter()` method:

```
m = /^(?:(a)(b)|(c)(d))$/.exec('ab').filter(Boolean);
//=> ["ab", "a", "b"]
```

Comment: Simple as that, of course. Didn't see this obvious solution while thinking about the regular expression itself. Thanks, will accept when I can (in 10 minutes).

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = /^(a)(b)$/.exec(value) || /^(c)(d)$/.exec(value);
```